# Fatal Error Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in... Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php:259 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php(259): file_put_contents('', '<?php return ar...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php(227): PrestaShopAutoload->dumpFile('/Applications/X...', '<?php return ar...') #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php(66): PrestaShopAutoload->generateIndex() #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php(78): PrestaShopAutoload->__construct() #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php(349): PrestaShopAutoload::getInstance() #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/config/autoload.php(31): require_once('/Applications/X...') #6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/config/config.inc.php(38): require_once('/Applications/X...') #7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/admin259xxrxvt/index.php(40): require('/Applications/X...') #8 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inconceptco/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php on line 259

I am new to SQl and I can't find the error that makes the page in XAMPP look blank, it tells me that this is the line where the error is. They help me?

Comment: This ia not an sql error message.

Comment: It seems the first parameter of the dumpFile method is not a correct filename. Can you please add this code: var_dump($filename);exit; at the beginning of the dumpFile method in /classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php and post the result here after reloading the page? Then please don't forget to remove the code.